# Windows server 2012 R2 Redeploying application group policy

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, deployment

I have an Active Directory environment with almost 750 client,
i have deployed application xyz-v1.msi through group policy

now we have xyz-v2.msi which requires previous version to be uninstalled completely

whats the best and most efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: You need to specify if the existing policy is configured to "uninstall this application when it falls out of the scope of management".

Comment: It's not configured, I simply clicked remove on the policy

Comment: Is it for assignment to computers or users?

Comment: Assigned To computers

Comment: I don't think there is a really good way to do this. There would need to be a computer startup script that runs `msiexec /x <productId>  /quiet /norestart /l* C:\Windows\ProductUninstall.log`. But there could be several reasons why that may not work. A shutdown script may provide better results, but not everyone shuts down their computer.